# Using findall function in module re for python

Tags: python, function, findall

I wrote code like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> url='<a href="C:\python34\koala.jpg">jpg</a><font size="10">'
>>> print(re.findall('href="(.*?)"><',url))
```

I except result

```
C:\python34\koala.jpg">jpg</a
```

But I can see only this result :

```
[]
```

why is this happening?

I did not know why I have this result in console.
Please help me.
I am using python 3.4 and windows8.1.

Comment: Why would you expect it such when your capturing group is inside quotes?

Comment: Never use regex to parse html : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want the `>jpg</a` part too. If yes then you can use this:

```
>>> re.findall('href="([^"]*">[^<]*</a)',url)
['C:\\python34\\koala.jpg">jpg</a']
```

If you need only the `href` attributes value then you can use:

```
>>> re.findall('href="([^"]*")',url)
['C:\\python34\\koala.jpg"']
```